# Process status of the past time

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-kernel, process

The command 'ps' gives current status of the processes. Is there any way to find the status of a particular process in the past: say I would like to know the status of a particular process 48 hours before from now?

I have a unit crashing and wanted to know the status of different processes during the exact time when the crash occurred.

Comment: Unless you have already set up monitoring on the process the answer is no.

Comment: @Raman Sailopal No, I do not have any monitoring setup for the processes. Following command gives the uptime of the process:                        ls -al /proc | grep <Process id>                                                                 But need to know the state of the process at a older time.

Comment: Is the past in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, commands such `ps` and `top` show only the current status of processes. There's no way to know what the process status was in the past unless you already set up a monitoring system.

For the future, you can set up `atop` to log process status. From its manpage:

> In order to store system- and process level statistics for long-term analysis (e.g. to check the system load and the active processes running yesterday between 3:00 and 4:00 PM), atop can store the system- and process level statistics in compressed binary format in a raw file with the flag -w followed by the filename. If this file already exists and is recognized as a raw data file, atop will append new samples to the file (starting with a sample which reflects the activity since boot); if the file does not exist, it will be created.
>
> By default only processes which have been active during the interval are stored in the raw file. When the flag -a is specified, all processes will be stored.
>   The interval (default: 10 seconds) and number of samples (default: infinite) can be passed as last arguments. Instead of the number of samples, the flag -S can be used to indicate that atop should finish anyhow before midnight.

Clearly, and as already said, `atop` will start recording only from the moment you set it up.